# resizable object not working properly native js

Tags: javascript, html

In my project user can create as many objects as he wants and resize them. But there is some bug that causes resizing go super fast. When user creates one object, resize it, then create second object and resize it too, after resizing second object come back to first and resizing this first object is faster than mouse movement speed.

```js
//create
function create() { 
  const workArea = document.querySelector('.work-area');
  let divParent = document.createElement("div");
  divParent.className = "divParent";
  
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "div";

  divParent.appendChild(div);
  workArea.appendChild(divParent);
   
  var resizerNE = document.createElement("div");
  resizerNE.className = "resizerNE";
  resizerNE.classList.add("resizer");

  var resizerSE = document.createElement("div");
  resizerSE.className = "resizerSE";
  resizerSE.classList.add("resizer");

  var resizerSW = document.createElement("div");
  resizerSW.className = "resizerSW";
  resizerSW.classList.add("resizer");

  var resizerNW = document.createElement("div");
  resizerNW.className = "resizerNW";
  resizerNW.classList.add("resizer");
      
      
  divParent.appendChild(resizerNE);
  divParent.appendChild(resizerSE);
  divParent.appendChild(resizerSW);
  divParent.appendChild(resizerNW);    
//resize
let el;
      const resizer = document.querySelectorAll(".resizer");
      resizer.forEach(function(thisresizer) {
        thisresizer.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
          el = this.parentNode;
        });
      });

      let isResizing = false;

      const resizers = document.querySelectorAll(".resizer");
      let currentResizer;

      for (let resizer of resizers) {
        resizer.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);

        function mousedown(e) {
          currentResizer = e.target;
          isResizing = true;

          //console.log(el);

          let prevX = e.clientX;
          let prevY = e.clientY;

          window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
          window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

          function mousemove(e) {
            const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

            if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerSE")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
              el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerSW")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
              el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
              el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerNE")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
              el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
              el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerNW")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
              el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
              el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
              el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerN")) {
              el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
              el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerE")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerS")) {
              el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
            } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerW")) {
              el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
              el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
            }

            el.children[0].style.width = el.style.width;
            el.children[0].style.height = el.style.height;

            //console.log("prevX: " + prevX + " prevY: " + prevY);
            prevX = e.clientX;
            prevY = e.clientY;
          }

          function mouseup() {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
            window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
            isResizing = false;
          }
        }
      }
      }
```

```css
.work-area{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}


.divParent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background:black
}

.div{
  background: #555555;
}

.resizer {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  border: 1px solid #2872c7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.resizerSE {
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}

.resizerNE {
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}

.resizerSW {
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.resizerNW {
  left: -6px;
  top: -6px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create()">Create</button>

<div class="work-area">
</div>
```

Comment: if you like the answer pls vote & accept

Comment: i couldn't  find the problem unless i rearranged the code i think you should use it that way it's better

Comment: if need more explaining tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally

i spend more than hour to find a way to overcome the problem

Which is  **Every Time you create objects  you add listeners to the previous resizers that's why every new object makes resizing the previous ones faster**

**in other words the browser moves more steps per mousemove event**

only change is

`const resizers = document.querySelectorAll(".resizer");`

to

`const resizers = divParent.querySelectorAll(".resizer");`

also in my answer i  rearranged your code making it simpler to read & smaller

```js
//create
function create() {
  const workArea = document.querySelector(".work-area");

  let divParent = document.createElement("div");
  divParent.className = "divParent";

  workArea.appendChild(divParent);

  NewDiv = cls => {
    let elm = document.createElement("div");
    elm.className = cls;
    divParent.appendChild(elm);
  };

  let div = NewDiv("div");

  let resizerNE = NewDiv("resizerNE resizer");

  let resizerSE = NewDiv("resizerSE resizer");

  let resizerSW = NewDiv("resizerSW resizer");

  let resizerNW = NewDiv("resizerNW resizer");

  //resize
  let el;
  let isResizing = false;

  const resizers = divParent.querySelectorAll(".resizer");
  let currentResizer;
  let prevX;
  let prevY;

  function mousedown(e) {
    el = this.parentNode;
    currentResizer = e.target;
    isResizing = true;
    prevX = e.clientX;
    prevY = e.clientY;
    workArea.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    workArea.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
  for (let resizer of resizers) {
    resizer.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);
  }

  function mousemove(e) {
    if (isResizing) {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerSE")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerSW")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerNE")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerNW")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerN")) {
        el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerE")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerS")) {
        el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("resizerW")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      }

      el.children[0].style.width = el.style.width;
      el.children[0].style.height = el.style.height;

      //console.log("prevX: " + prevX + " prevY: " + prevY);
      prevX = e.clientX;
      prevY = e.clientY;
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    isResizing = false;
    workArea.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
    workArea.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  }
}
```

```css
.work-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.divParent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}

.div {
  background: #555555;
}

.resizer {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  border: 1px solid #2872c7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.resizerSE {
  right: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}

.resizerNE {
  top: -6px;
  right: -6px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}

.resizerSW {
  left: -6px;
  bottom: -6px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.resizerNW {
  left: -6px;
  top: -6px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="create()">Create</button>

  <div class="work-area"></div>
</body>
```